SVG Rendering Issues on iOS 18 Beta: Parabolic Graphs Breaking
I have an SVG file that primarily consists of paths and lines, used to render graphs within a Cordova application. After updating to the latest iOS 18 beta, I noticed that the parabolic graphs drawn using paths are not rendering correctly—they appear broken, especially at the ends.
To further investigate, I transferred an HTML file containing the SVG elements to an iPad running iOS 18 beta 7 and opened it using the Files app. The issue persists, with the SVG paths appearing broken. If you zoom in on the components slightly, the problem becomes even more noticeable.
What's puzzling is that this SVG renders perfectly across all major browsers, including Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and even on Safari on older iOS versions. The issue seems isolated to the latest iOS 18 beta.
Has anyone else encountered similar issues with SVG rendering on iOS 18 beta? I've attached the HTML file for reference.
I've attached an image preview of the broken SVG on the iPad running iOS 18 beta, as well as the HTML file for reference.

Any insights or workarounds would be greatly appreciated!


 <svg width="99%" height="100%" viewBox="0 -30 676 480" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" style="height:100%; width:100%; max-height:100%; max-width:100%; position:absolute; will-change: transform; left:50%; top:50%; transform:translate(-49%,-50%); -webkit-transform:translate(-49%,-50%); overflow:visible;">
         <g transform="translate(0,0) scale(1, 1)" class="lineholder">
            <line class="l1 s-black h-line" x1="-15" x2="676" y1="400" y2="400"></line>
            <line class="l1 s-black v-line" stroke="black" strokewidth="2" x1="-15" x2="-15" y1="0" y2="400"></line>
            <line stroke="#999999" stroke-width=".5" x1="31" x2="31" y1="0" y2="400"></line>
            <line stroke="#999999" stroke-width=".5" x1="77" x2="77" y1="0" y2="400"></line>
            <line stroke="#999999" stroke-width=".5" x1="123" x2="123" y1="0" y2="400"></line>
            <line stroke="#999999" stroke-width=".5" x1="169" x2="169" y1="0" y2="400"></line>
            <line stroke="#999999" stroke-width=".5" x1="215" x2="215" y1="0" y2="400"></line>
            <line stroke="#999999" stroke-width=".5" x1="261" x2="261" y1="0" y2="400"></line>
            <line stroke="#999999" stroke-width=".5" x1="307" x2="307" y1="0" y2="400"></line>
            <line stroke="#999999" stroke-width=".5" x1="353" x2="353" y1="0" y2="400"></line>
            <line stroke="#999999" stroke-width=".5" x1="399" x2="399" y1="0" y2="400"></line>
            <line stroke="#999999" stroke-width=".5" x1="445" x2="445" y1="0" y2="400"></line>
            <line stroke="#999999" stroke-width=".5" x1="491" x2="491" y1="0" y2="400"></line>
            <line stroke="#999999" stroke-width=".5" x1="537" x2="537" y1="0" y2="400"></line>
            <line stroke="#999999" stroke-width=".5" x1="583" x2="583" y1="0" y2="400"></line>
            <line stroke="#999999" stroke-width=".5" x1="629" x2="629" y1="0" y2="400"></line>
            <line stroke="#999999" stroke-width=".5" x1="675" x2="675" y1="0" y2="400"></line>
            <line stroke="#999999" stroke-width=".5" x1="-15" x2="676" y1="360" y2="360"></line>
            <line stroke="#999999" stroke-width=".5" x1="-15" x2="676" y1="320" y2="320"></line>
            <line stroke="#999999" stroke-width=".5" x1="-15" x2="676" y1="280" y2="280"></line>
            <line stroke="#999999" stroke-width=".5" x1="-15" x2="676" y1="240" y2="240"></line>
            <line stroke="#999999" stroke-width=".5" x1="-15" x2="676" y1="200" y2="200"></line>
            <line stroke="#999999" stroke-width=".5" x1="-15" x2="676" y1="160" y2="160"></line>
            <line stroke="#999999" stroke-width=".5" x1="-15" x2="676" y1="120" y2="120"></line>
            <line stroke="#999999" stroke-width=".5" x1="-15" x2="676" y1="80" y2="80"></line>
            <line stroke="#999999" stroke-width=".5" x1="-15" x2="676" y1="40" y2="40"></line>
            <line stroke="#999999" stroke-width=".5" x1="-15" x2="676" y1="0" y2="0"></line>
         </g>
         <g transform="translate(15, 400) scale(1, -1)" class="parabola_pathholder" style="z-index: 800;">
            <path class="signal" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#999999" data-ssid="ABC" data-mac="00:00:00:00:00:00" d="M430,0 Q522,496 614,0"></path>
            <path class="signal" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#999999" data-ssid="ABC" data-mac="00:00:00:00:00:00" d="M430,0 Q522,496 614,0"></path>
            <path class="signal" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#999999" data-ssid="BABC" data-mac="00:00:00:00:00:00" d="M430,0 Q522,496 614,0"></path>
            <path class="signal" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#999999" data-ssid="ABC" data-mac="00:00:00:00:00:00" d="M430,0 Q522,136 614,0"></path>
            <path class="signal" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#999999" data-ssid="ABC" data-mac="00:00:00:00:00:00" d="M430,0 Q522,128 614,0"></path>
            <path class="signal" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#999999" data-ssid="ABC" data-mac="00:00:00:00:00:00" d="M246,0 Q430,72 614,0"></path>
            <path class="signal" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#999999" data-ssid="BABC" data-mac="00:00:00:00:00:00" d="M430,0 Q522,136 614,0"></path>
            <path class="signal" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#999999" data-ssid="ABC" data-mac="00:00:00:00:00:00" d="M430,0 Q522,144 614,0"></path>
            <path class="signal" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#999999" data-ssid="JABC" data-mac="00:00:00:00:00:00" d="M430,0 Q522,64 614,0"></path>
            <path class="signal" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#999999" data-ssid="ABC" data-mac="00:00:00:00:00:00" d="M200,0 Q384,64 568,0"></path>
            <path class="signal" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#999999" data-ssid="ABC" data-mac="00:00:00:00:00:00" d="M200,0 Q292,328 384,0"></path>
            <path class="signal" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#999999" data-ssid="ABC" data-mac="00:00:00:00:00:00" d="M200,0 Q292,320 384,0"></path>
            <path class="signal" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#999999" data-ssid="ABC" data-mac="00:00:00:00:00:00" d="M200,0 Q292,320 384,0"></path>
            <path class="signal" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#999999" data-ssid="ABC" data-mac="00:00:00:00:00:00" d="M200,0 Q292,231.99999999999997 384,0"></path>
            <path class="signal" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#999999" data-ssid="ABC" data-mac="00:00:00:00:00:00" d="M200,0 Q292,224.00000000000003 384,0"></path>
            <path class="signal" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#999999" data-ssid="ABC" data-mac="00:00:00:00:00:00" d="M200,0 Q292,240 384,0"></path>
            <path class="signal" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#999999" data-ssid="ABC" data-mac="00:00:00:00:00:00" d="M200,0 Q292,240 384,0"></path>
            <path class="signal" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#999999" data-ssid="ABC" data-mac="00:00:00:00:00:00" d="M246,0 Q430,32 614,0"></path>
            <path class="signal" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#999999" data-ssid="ABC" data-mac="00:00:00:00:00:00" d="M62,0 Q154,80 246,0"></path>
            <path class="signal" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#999999" data-ssid="ABC" data-mac="00:00:00:00:00:00" d="M430,0 Q522,64 614,0"></path>
            <path class="signal" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#999999" data-ssid="ABC" data-mac="00:00:00:00:00:00" d="M-30,0 Q62,104 154,0"></path>
            <path class="signal" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#999999" data-ssid="BABC" data-mac="00:00:00:00:00:00" d="M430,0 Q522,48 614,0"></path>
            <path class="signal" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#999999" data-ssid="ABC" data-mac="00:00:00:00:00:00" d="M200,0 Q292,104 384,0"></path>
            <path class="signal" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#999999" data-ssid="BABC" data-mac="00:00:00:00:00:00" d="M200,0 Q292,96 384,0"></path>
            <path class="signal" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#999999" data-ssid="ABC" data-mac="00:00:00:00:00:00" d="M200,0 Q292,96 384,0"></path>
            <path class="signal" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#999999" data-ssid="ABC" data-mac="00:00:00:00:00:00" d="M62,0 Q154,112.00000000000001 246,0"></path>
            <path class="signal" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#999999" data-ssid="ABC" data-mac="00:00:00:00:00:00" d="M-30,0 Q62,128 154,0"></path>
            <path class="signal" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#999999" data-ssid="ABC" data-mac="00:00:00:00:00:00" d="M200,0 Q292,96 384,0"></path>
         </g>
         <g transform="translate(15, 400) scale(1, -1)" class="zigbee_parabola_pathholder"></g>
         <g transform="translate(15, 400) scale(1, -1)" class="cu_pathholder" style="z-index: 500;">
            <rect class="cu-interference" x="46.5" y="0" width="31" height="48" data-channel="1"></rect>
            <rect class="cu-interference" x="276.5" y="0" width="31" height="8" data-channel="6"></rect>
            <rect class="cu-interference" x="506.5" y="0" width="31" height="12" data-channel="11"></rect>
            <rect class="cu-interference" x="322.5" y="0" width="31" height="12" data-channel="7"></rect>
            <rect class="cu-interference" x="92.5" y="0" width="31" height="36" data-channel="2"></rect>
            <rect class="cu-interference" x="138.5" y="0" width="31" height="32" data-channel="3"></rect>
            <rect class="cu-interference" x="184.5" y="0" width="31" height="24" data-channel="4"></rect>
            <rect class="cu-interference" x="230.5" y="0" width="31" height="12" data-channel="5"></rect>
            <rect class="cu-interference" x="368.5" y="0" width="31" height="12" data-channel="8"></rect>
            <polyline class="cu-max" data-channel="1" points="62,92,67,97,57,97,62,92" style="opacity: 0.99;"></polyline>
            <polyline class="cu-max" data-channel="6" points="292,12,297,17,287,17,292,12" style="opacity: 0.99;"></polyline>
            <polyline class="cu-max" data-channel="11" points="522,20,527,25,517,25,522,20" style="opacity: 0.99;"></polyline>
            <polyline class="cu-max" data-channel="7" points="338,24,343,29,333,29,338,24" style="opacity: 0.99;"></polyline>
            <polyline class="cu-max" data-channel="2" points="108,72,113,77,103,77,108,72" style="opacity: 0.99;"></polyline>
            <polyline class="cu-max" data-channel="3" points="154,48,159,53,149,53,154,48" style="opacity: 0.99;"></polyline>
            <polyline class="cu-max" data-channel="4" points="200,44,205,49,195,49,200,44" style="opacity: 0.99;"></polyline>
            <polyline class="cu-max" data-channel="5" points="246,16,251,21,241,21,246,16" style="opacity: 0.99;"></polyline>
            <polyline class="cu-max" data-channel="8" points="384,28,389,33,379,33,384,28" style="opacity: 0.99;"></polyline>
            <polyline class="cu-min" points="62,4,57,0,67,0,62,4" data-channel="1" style="opacity: 1;"></polyline>
            <polyline class="cu-min" points="292,4,287,0,297,0,292,4" data-channel="6" style="opacity: 1;"></polyline>
            <polyline class="cu-min" points="522,8,517,4,527,4,522,8" data-channel="11" style="opacity: 1;"></polyline>
            <polyline class="cu-min" points="338,8,333,4,343,4,338,8" data-channel="7" style="opacity: 1;"></polyline>
            <polyline class="cu-min" points="108,24,103,20,113,20,108,24" data-channel="2" style="opacity: 1;"></polyline>
            <polyline class="cu-min" points="154,24,149,20,159,20,154,24" data-channel="3" style="opacity: 1;"></polyline>
            <polyline class="cu-min" points="200,16,195,12,205,12,200,16" data-channel="4" style="opacity: 1;"></polyline>
            <polyline class="cu-min" points="246,8,241,4,251,4,246,8" data-channel="5" style="opacity: 1;"></polyline>
            <polyline class="cu-min" points="384,8,379,4,389,4,384,8" data-channel="8" style="opacity: 1;"></polyline>
            <rect class="cu-interference" x="414.5" y="0" width="31" height="56.00000000000001" data-channel="9"></rect>
            <polyline class="cu-max" data-channel="9" points="430,92,435,97,425,97,430,92" style="opacity: 0.99;"></polyline>
            <polyline class="cu-min" points="430,52,425,48,435,48,430,52" data-channel="9" style="opacity: 1;"></polyline>
            <rect class="cu-interference" x="460.5" y="0" width="31" height="12" data-channel="10"></rect>
            <polyline class="cu-max" data-channel="10" points="476,16,481,21,471,21,476,16" style="opacity: 0.99;"></polyline>
            <polyline class="cu-min" points="476,4,471,0,481,0,476,4" data-channel="10" style="opacity: 1;"></polyline>
         </g>
         <g class="v-label-holder" transform="translate(-45,0)">
            <rect class="v-label-background" fill="#fff" x="-70" y="0" width="100" height="403"></rect>
            <text transform="translate(0,0) scale(1, 1)" class="text-labels v-text-labels" textLength="20" x="2" y="365">-90</text>
            <text transform="translate(0,0) scale(1, 1)" class="text-labels v-text-labels" textLength="20" x="2" y="325">-80</text>
            <text transform="translate(0,0) scale(1, 1)" class="text-labels v-text-labels" textLength="20" x="2" y="285">-70</text>
            <text transform="translate(0,0) scale(1, 1)" class="text-labels v-text-labels" textLength="20" x="2" y="245">-60</text>
            <text transform="translate(0,0) scale(1, 1)" class="text-labels v-text-labels" textLength="20" x="2" y="205">-50</text>
            <text transform="translate(0,0) scale(1, 1)" class="text-labels v-text-labels" textLength="20" x="2" y="165">-40</text>
            <text transform="translate(0,0) scale(1, 1)" class="text-labels v-text-labels" textLength="20" x="2" y="125">-30</text>
            <text transform="translate(0,0) scale(1, 1)" class="text-labels v-text-labels" textLength="20" x="2" y="85">-20</text>
            <text transform="translate(0,0) scale(1, 1)" class="text-labels v-text-labels" textLength="20" x="2" y="45">-10</text>
            <text transform="translate(0,0) scale(1, 1)" class="text-labels v-text-labels" textLength="20" x="2" y="5">0</text>
            <text transform="translate(0,0) rotate(270) scale(1, 1)" class="text-labels v-text-labels v-text-name" x="-250" y="-4">Y- Axis (Num)</text>
         </g>
         <g class="ssid-label-holder" transform="translate(-45,0)">
            <text class="text-h-labels parabola-labels" x="577" y="132" data-index="0" display="none" style="text-anchor: middle;">ABC</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels parabola-labels" x="577" y="132" data-index="1" display="none" style="text-anchor: middle;">ABC</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels parabola-labels" x="577" y="132" data-index="2" display="none" style="text-anchor: middle;">ABC</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels parabola-labels" x="577" y="312" data-index="3" display="none" style="text-anchor: middle;">ABC</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels parabola-labels" x="577" y="316" data-index="4" display="none" style="text-anchor: middle;">ABC</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels parabola-labels" x="485" y="344" data-index="5" display="none" style="text-anchor: middle;">ABC</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels parabola-labels" x="577" y="312" data-index="6" display="none" style="text-anchor: middle;">ABC</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels parabola-labels" x="577" y="308" data-index="7" display="none" style="text-anchor: middle;">ABC</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels parabola-labels" x="577" y="348" data-index="8" display="none" style="text-anchor: middle;">ABC</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels parabola-labels" x="439" y="348" data-index="9" display="none" style="text-anchor: middle;">ABC</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels parabola-labels" x="347" y="216" data-index="10" display="none" style="text-anchor: middle;">ABC</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels parabola-labels" x="347" y="220" data-index="11" display="none" style="text-anchor: middle;">ABC</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels parabola-labels" x="347" y="220" data-index="12" display="none" style="text-anchor: middle;">ABC</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels parabola-labels" x="347" y="264" data-index="13" display="none" style="text-anchor: middle;">ABC</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels parabola-labels" x="347" y="268" data-index="14" display="none" style="text-anchor: middle;">BABC</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels parabola-labels" x="347" y="260" data-index="15" display="none" style="text-anchor: middle;">ABC</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels parabola-labels" x="347" y="260" data-index="16" display="none" style="text-anchor: middle;">ABC</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels parabola-labels" x="485" y="364" data-index="17" display="none" style="text-anchor: middle;">ABC</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels parabola-labels" x="209" y="340" data-index="18" display="none" style="text-anchor: middle;">ABC</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels parabola-labels" x="577" y="348" data-index="19" display="none" style="text-anchor: middle;">JABC</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels parabola-labels" x="117" y="328" data-index="20" display="none" style="text-anchor: middle;">ABC</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels parabola-labels" x="577" y="356" data-index="21" display="none" style="text-anchor: middle;">ABC</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels parabola-labels" x="347" y="328" data-index="22" display="none" style="text-anchor: middle;">ABC</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels parabola-labels" x="347" y="332" data-index="23" display="none" style="text-anchor: middle;">ABC</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels parabola-labels" x="347" y="332" data-index="24" display="none" style="text-anchor: middle;">BABC</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels parabola-labels" x="209" y="324" data-index="25" display="none" style="text-anchor: middle;">ABC</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels parabola-labels" x="117" y="316" data-index="26" display="none" style="text-anchor: middle;">BABC</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels parabola-labels" x="347" y="332" data-index="27" display="none" style="text-anchor: middle;">ABC</text>
         </g>
         <g class="v-cu-label-holder interference">
            <rect class="v-label-background" fill="#fff" x="676" y="0" width="100" height="403"></rect>
            <text transform="translate(0,0) scale(1, 1)" class="text-labels v-text-labels" textLength="30" x="681" y="365">10%</text>
            <text transform="translate(0,0) scale(1, 1)" class="text-labels v-text-labels" textLength="30" x="681" y="325">20%</text>
            <text transform="translate(0,0) scale(1, 1)" class="text-labels v-text-labels" textLength="30" x="681" y="285">30%</text>
            <text transform="translate(0,0) scale(1, 1)" class="text-labels v-text-labels" textLength="30" x="681" y="245">40%</text>
            <text transform="translate(0,0) scale(1, 1)" class="text-labels v-text-labels" textLength="30" x="681" y="205">50%</text>
            <text transform="translate(0,0) scale(1, 1)" class="text-labels v-text-labels" textLength="30" x="681" y="165">60%</text>
            <text transform="translate(0,0) scale(1, 1)" class="text-labels v-text-labels" textLength="30" x="681" y="125">70%</text>
            <text transform="translate(0,0) scale(1, 1)" class="text-labels v-text-labels" textLength="30" x="681" y="85">80%</text>
            <text transform="translate(0,0) scale(1, 1)" class="text-labels v-text-labels" textLength="30" x="681" y="45">90%</text>
            <text transform="translate(0,0) scale(1, 1)" class="text-labels v-text-labels" textLength="30" x="681" y="5">100%</text>
            <text transform="translate(0,0) rotate(90) scale(1, 1)" class="text-labels v-text-labels v-text-name" x="140" y="-716">Y-Asis (%)</text>
         </g>
         <g transform="translate(0,0) scale(1, 1)" class="h-label-holder">
            <text class="text-h-labels" textLength="15" x="26" y="415"></text>
            <text class="text-h-labels" textLength="15" x="72" y="415">1</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels" textLength="15" x="118" y="415">2</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels" textLength="15" x="164" y="415">3</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels" textLength="15" x="210" y="415">4</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels" textLength="15" x="256" y="415">5</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels" textLength="15" x="302" y="415">6</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels" textLength="15" x="348" y="415">7</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels" textLength="15" x="394" y="415">8</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels" textLength="15" x="440" y="415">9</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels" textLength="15" x="486" y="415">10</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels" textLength="15" x="532" y="415">11</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels" textLength="15" x="578" y="415">12</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels" textLength="15" x="624" y="415">13</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels" textLength="15" x="670" y="415">14</text>
            <text class="text-h-labels" textLength="200" x="268" y="435">X-Axis</text>
         </g>
      </svg>




Report webkit bugs to the webkit bugtracker

Reported bug here: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=279105
Thanks !!
